# Google Drive API - Drive.Files class has no insert () method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, google-drive-api

I added 3 dependencies to the project

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev59-1.22.0'
```

However, the `Drive.Files` class does not have the `insert()` method https://zapodaj.net/b19acf76dccdb.png.html https://zapodaj.net/4e6df99cee1bf.png.html

Why?

Comment: `Drive.Files#insert()` with no arguments does not exist.  Both versions of the `insert()` method take arguments.  Your question is unclear, what are you expecting and why? Also, include the Java code in your question.

Comment: In this film https://youtu.be/Ymqudfh4ovI?t=20m1s you can see.

Comment: It makes no difference what you see in some random video on the Internet.  Look at the Javadoc to see what methods are available.  There is no zero-argument `insert()` method.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.html In my code I show that such a method is not available at all.

Answer (score 3):

In v3 the appropriate method is create(), not insert()